# Next.js application not reading environment variables from Azure App Application Settings

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a Next.js application to Azure and I am noticing that the application is not reading from the Application Settings environment variables when I run the application.  For example, I created a simple variable called "NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_ENV" in the Azure Application Settings.

It seems like from the documentation on Next.js that the environment variables are set at build time.

Our DevOps team is trying to leverage a build once; deploy anywhere approach and having the application read from the Application Settings is what we are trying to do.

Here is the variables declared locally in the local **.env** file:
[image]

Here is the **next.js.config** file, which I added to the env section, not sure if that is needed or not.
[image]

**When I print the variable out, it works:**

[image]
[image]

**However, once the application is deployed to Azure; the variable to is not being read.**

[image]

Is it possible to read from Application Settings in Azure from Next.js? Thank you!

Comment: How you are deploying your App?

Comment: Try reading App Settings as `console.log(process.env.APPSETTING_NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_ENV);`

Comment: @Harshitha - We are deploying through Azure DevOps Pipelines

Comment: Instead of Images, please provide code snippets.

Comment: Any luck with this? Running into the same issue

Comment: Seems like we have to stick the front-end env variables inside the github actions files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

To access front-end env variables from an Azure Static app, you need add the env variables inside of your job configuration. For Azure Pipelines, the relevant part should look like:

```
...

inputs:
  app_location: 'src'
  api_location: 'api'
  output_location: 'public'
  azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
env: # Add environment variables here
  HUGO_VERSION: 0.58.0
```

For Github Actions:

```
...

with:
  azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
  repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  action: 'upload'
  app_location: 'src'
  api_location: 'api'
  output_location: 'public'
env: # Add environment variables here
  HUGO_VERSION: 0.58.0
```

Examples taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#environment-variables